# Use of undeclared type AudioDeviceID in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio

I have added and imported `AudioToolbox` framework. But my project is not able to see the file `AudioDeviceID`, `AudioObjectPropertyAddress`. It gives the error, `Use of undeclared type 'AudioDeviceID'`. I tried a [sample Core Audio project](https://github.com/derekli66/Learning-Core-Audio-Swift-SampleCode/blob/master/CH04_Recorder-Swift/CH04_Recorder-Swift/main.swift) and it works fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I figured, this is available only on mac: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/audiodeviceid

Comment: So answer your own question. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AudioDeviceID` is currently available for macOS 10.0+ only. It is not available on iOS.